# add class automatically img object with htmlpurifier

Tags: htmlpurifier, purify

firstly sorry for my broken english.

before purify:

```
<img src="xxx.jpg"/>
```

after purify:

```
<img src="xxx.jpg" class="myclass" />
```

how can i do with html purifier?

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, why don't you just put user content in a div with id `content` and then use the CSS selector `#content img`?